# Fix Matplotlib xlim and ylim over replots for animation purposes

Tags: opencv, matplotlib, scatter

Was trying to quickly view my wip particle simulator and so I used matplotlib to plot the particles. Howevever, matplotlib seems to make small adjustments inbetween images. (The images are written in to video using cv2 videowriter).

Does anyone know how to hardset the ranges? (currently using xlim and ylim)

```
fig.tight_layout()
plt.xlim(xmin-x_axis_buffer,xmax+x_axis_buffer)
plt.ylim(ymin-y_axis_buffer,ymax+y_axis_buffer)


for i in range(nIters):
        plt.scatter(data[i,:,0],data[i,:,1],c=[i for i in range(nParticles)],cmap="gist_rainbow")
        fig.set_size_inches(8, 6)
        _=f'{i:04}.png'
        plt.savefig(_, dpi=100)
        plt.cla()
```

[output_from_video.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6v2y.gif)

Comment: Use `plt.xlim(-1, 1)` and `plt.ylim(-1, 1)` to set the limits before you call `plt.savefig`

Comment: It works! so set lim after plotting. ok.